How to determine the default TextStyle of MenuItemButtons
It says docs.flutter.dev/menus-text-style:
The default text style for MenuItemButton [...] is TextTheme.labelLarge for Material 3.
If I now want to add a Text widget in a Column with several MenuItemButtons in such a way that the TextStyle is equalized, I could write:
Column(
  children: [
    Text(
      'some text',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
    ),
    MenuItemButton(child: Text('some text'),
    MenuItemButton(child: Text('some text'),
  ],
),

Is it possible to programmatically determine the TextStyle of MenuItemButtons (Material 3, "neutral" WidgetState)?
